# A verb to describe a smart response to a joke

Tags: word-request

> Jenny: Why did you come home earlier than me?
>
> Jack: Well, because I am smarter than you. That's why!   :)
>
> Jenny: But how come only today?  :)
>
> Jack:  :(

In the conversation above we can see that Jenny has brilliantly responded to Jack's joke in such a way that his joke came back on him, meaning that he got trapped by his own joke.

I wonder what past participle in English would precisely describe Jenny's response here. Should it be something like:

1. Jenny never leaves any of his jokes **unanswered**.

or

2. Jenny never leaves any of his jokes **unreturned**.

or

3. Jenny never leaves any of his jokes **not come back**.

or

4. Jenny never leaves any of his jokes **unequaled**.

or

5. Jenny never leaves any of his jokes **unpaid** back.

or

6. Jenny never leaves any of his jokes ____________. ?

Comment: You could also say *the joke is on Jack*.

Comment: Thanks, but how would that go together with "Jenny"? "Jenny always makes [sure/it no doubt] that Jack's jokes are on him"? Or is there any other and better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word **riposte** seems appropriate. According to the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/riposte), it means

> **riposte:** a quick and clever remark, often made in answer to a criticism

You would have to change the sentence a little, like this:

> Jenny always has a riposte for this jokes

A more idiomatic expression is **[put-down](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/put-down)** which means

> **put-down**: an unkind remark that makes someone seem silly

It can be used in the same way:

> Jenny always has a put-down for this jokes

Comment: Well, thanks, but I was asking for a past participle.

Comment: Looking for a particular part of speech always gets people into trouble.  Sometimes the sense in English is not conveyed by a past participle.